# When parsing JSON with java, how to getText() bounded by a maximum amount?

Tags: java, jackson, gson, fasterxml

I am attempting to parse the output of Apache Tika Server's `rmeta` web servivce endpoint: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/TikaServer#TikaServer-RecursiveMetadataandContent

It's payloads look like the following:

```
[
 {"Application-Name":"Microsoft Office Word",
  "Application-Version":"15.0000",
  "X-Parsed-By":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser","org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.OOXMLParser"],
  "X-TIKA:content":"this content string can be many MB large"
  ...
 },
 {"Content-Encoding":"ISO-8859-1",
  "Content-Length":"8",
  "Content-Type":"text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1"
  "X-TIKA:content":"again, this content string can be many MB large",
  ...
 }
 ...
]
```

As indicated, the `X-TIKA:content` strings can be quite oppressively large. Enough to OOM my JVM if I load the entire string into memory.

So if I were to use `JsonParser.getText()` like this:

```
  private void parseRmetaResponse(CloseableHttpResponse response) {
      ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
      JsonFactory jsonFactory = objectMapper.getFactory();
      JsonParser jsonParser = jsonFactory.createParser(response.getEntity().getContent());
      JsonToken arrayStartToken = jsonParser.nextToken();
      if (arrayStartToken != JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("The first element of the Json structure was expected to be a start array token, but it was: " + arrayStartToken);
      }


      JsonToken nextToken = jsonParser.nextToken();
      while (nextToken != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
        parseNextField(jsonParser);
      }

  }

  private String getTextContents(JsonParser jsonParser, OutputStream os, Metadata metadata) throws IOException {
    String nextAttr = jsonParser.nextFieldName();
    if ("X-TIKA:content".equals(nextAttr)) {
      return jsonParser.getText();
    }
    // ...
  }
```

It would be prone to OOM crashes because I cannot load all of that string in memory without eating up all the JVM heap.

Instead I have a maximum number of chars parameter `maxChars` that I want to stop reading chars from `X-TIKA:content` after I reach that number.

How can I say "get me text, but only read up to `maxChars` characters, and discard any additional characters"?

I can use GSON, Fasterxml Jackson, or any other library that helps me do what I need to do here.

Comment: at what point would u want the jsonParser to stop getting text?

Comment: after `maxParseChars` - a configurable value that I specify

Comment: couldn't you do a substring on it? from 0, to the maxParseChars

Comment: at that point it would be loaded into heap. so no.

Comment: ah yeah that's true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling [`String getText()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser.html#getText()), you can call [`int getText(Writer writer)`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser.html#getText(java.io.Writer)).

Give it a *custom* [`Writer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) that works similar to [`StringWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html), but discards any characters beyond a given threshold.

The you would use it like this:

```java
if ("X-TIKA:content".equals(nextAttr)) {
    try (LimitedStringWriter writer = new LimitedStringWriter(maxParseChars)) {
        jsonParser.getText(writer);
        return writer.toString();
    }
}
```

Writing the `LimitedStringWriter` class is your job to do.

---

*Added by questioner (Nicholas DiPiazza):*
Here is an example of an implementation you could use as an example: https://github.com/ow2-proactive/scheduling/blob/master/common/common-api/src/main/java/org/ow2/proactive/utils/BoundedStringWriter.java